# Variable error: unknown type name

Tags: c++, xcode

I have this code (just a snippet)

```
const Line & operator= (rhs : const Line &)
{
}
```

But I am getting:

> Unknown type name 'rhs'

What should I do?

Comment: Please don't use screenshots, include the actual code.

Comment: This is not Pascal/Delphi, the type has to come before the name, without colon

Comment: Stop. Don't press "submit" until you've a) taken a deep breath, b) learned about the authoring tools (markdown, live preview) on this website, c) look at what other, successful posts look like, d) review everything you're about to send at least twice.

Comment: Which learning resource taught you that C++ looks like this?

Comment: `What should I do?` Start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 2):

You need to write

```
Line& operator=(const Line& rhs)
```

Note the placement of `rhs`.

I've also dropped the `const` at the beginning of the line since the *conventional* thing to return when overriding assignment is a reference to self, not a `const` reference to self.